# Which word can I put?

Tags: grammar

If I wrote "you cant fix a broken plate or a hole in the wall. However, you cant fix a broken heart" 
Can the word "however" work here? If it cant what can i use instead?

Please i need an answer as soon as possible...
Thank you.

Comment: No, because there's no contrast in your two sentences. However is used to introduce a contrasting idea, etc. "You **can** do this; however, you **can't** do that." Perhaps you meant to say you *can* fix in your first sentence?

Comment: I meant the word can't in both sentences.. What can I put instead of however?

Comment: It's badly written, but if you need a word, use **also**. But again, it's not a good sentence. First, you *can* fix a broken plate and certainly a hole in the wall (I've patched a couple myself). If you want to connect negatives, use **nor**, but you'll still lose a can't. "You can't do x or y, nor can you do z."

Comment: Why can't you fix a broken plate or a hole in the wall?

Comment: The type of phrase you are trying to construct is an aphorism, which is a saying that describes a truth about life.  But if you really mean "can't" in both sentences, it doesn't work because it isn't true, as medica pointed out.  It would be like saying, "You can't lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink".

Answer (score 2):

First, the contraction "can't", needs an apostrophe.  Second, I think by your first "cant", you actually mean "*can*"..  As for your use of However, I don't think this phrase warrants two sentences, and would sound like more of an aphorism if you phrased it thus:

> You can fix a a broken plate or a hole in the wall, but you can't fix a broken heart.

Comment: no, she actually means can't.

Comment: Did she tell you this?  Why the 'However' in the second sentence?

Comment: yes, look in the comment section. that is the mystery of bad writing, I suppose.